# zabbix monitoring file size, path is depending on application name

Tags: zabbix

Hi I want to monitor the growth of the file size of a log file with zabbix but the path differs for every application.

The log file is in: d:\data[foo]\data\log\server.log where [foo] is an application name.

How can I monitor the growth file size. And when the growth is to fast I want to trigger an alert.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You create a [LLD discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery) to find all the files using a dedicated [user parameter](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/userparameters), and create a prototype item with `vfs.file.size[{#FULL_PATH}]`.

The corresponding prototype trigger can be a threshold, or a forecast. The first one is simpler, like "if file size is bigger than 10 MB".